# Override MaterialDesign check box style

Tags: wpf, checkbox, styles, material-design, controltemplate

So I have this `CheckBox` `Style` based on `MaterialDesignActionCheckBox`:

```
<Style x:Key="MaterialDesignActionAccentCheckBox2" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionCheckBox}">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
                     Width="15"
                     Height="15"
                     Fill="#353535"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                  <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And I did now wanted the `V` sign when the `CheckBox` is checked so I Make it `Transparent` (under `IsChecked` true) and put `Ellipse`.
After I added this `ControlTemplate.Triggers` I cannot see my `Ellipse`.
All I want to do is to show this `Ellipse` inside my `Checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Contol templates define the visual appearance, visual states, transitions between them and required controls for a control. Missing any of these components will lead to unexpected behavior. You can look up all required parts and states of a control on MSDN, e.g. for the `CheckBox` control:

- [CheckBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Your check box style lacks some controls and states and that is why it does not work. It is important to note that you cannot base a control template on another like it is possible for styles. Consequently, you have to copy and adapt an existing template or create your own from scratch. For *Material Design* you can find the styles and templates [at GitHub](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes).

The good news is that you might be able to achieve your goal much easier, as some parts of the default style, like the check mark for the action check box, can be overridden.

Create a style that is based on the `MaterialDesignActionCheckBox` style. Set a `PackIcon` as the value of the `ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent` property. You can specify the icon you like via the `Kind` property. You can have a look at the [`PackIconKind` enum](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/265cac1d9ffbf8ff84915acd9d3d8cc4cdb518ca/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/PackIconKind.cs#L14) to find all available icons.

```
<Style x:Key="EllipseMaterialDesignActionCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionCheckBox}">
   <Setter Property="wpf:ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent">
      <Setter.Value>
         <wpf:PackIcon Kind="Circle" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Instead of the pack icon, you could of course set your ellipse instead, just replace the pack icon with the code below. The `Fill` binding ensures that the ellipse will apply the `Foreground` color of the parent `CheckBox`.

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}}" Width="20" Height="20"/>
```

If you want to change the color of the check mark, you can either apply the color directly to the `Fill` property in the style or you add a setter to the `CheckBox` style that sets the `Foreground` property.

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#353535"/>
```

To use the style, reference it as `StaticResource` (or `DynamicResource` if you need).

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource EllipseMaterialDesignActionCheckBox}"/>
```

In order to apply the style automatically to all `CheckBox`es in scope, create an *implicit style*.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource EllipseMaterialDesignActionCheckBox}"/>
```

Here are a few screenshots for comparison, my primary and secondary colors are `DeepPurple` and `Lime`, yours may be different. The first box is the default one, the second is using the circle pack icon (using ellipse is just the same) and the last has your `Foreground` color applied.

[image: Check boxes in different styles.]